# Google+ y Android Studio editar compartir publicacion

Tags: android, google+

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que tiene la acción de compartir en Google+. Cuando uno comparte sale la publicación que voy a dejar a continuación en la imagen. La pregunta es:
¿Como puedo modificar la foto que sale marcada en marrón?
¿Como puedo modificar el texto de la foto que sale en rojo?

Quiero que las 2 cosas sean dinamicas. por ejemplo: Si comparto algo relacionado a un local que vende pizzas, que en la foto de la publicacion me salga la foto de ese lugar que vende pizzas y a su vez que me salga un texto descripitivo de ese lugar en la parte que esta resaltada en rojo.

Este es mi codigo que tengo para editar la publicacion que se comparte en Google+

> ```
>            Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(getApplication())
>                                     .setType("text/plain")
>                                     .setText("este es el titulo de la publicacion en G+")
>                                     .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
>                                     .getIntent();
>                             startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
> ```

[image]

Muchas gracias, espero ser claro con las preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver el código me es complicado ayudarte específicamente pero des de android utilizando la API de google plus puedes utilizar `setContentDeepLinkId` (consúltalo en el [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder.html#public-methods))

En concreto:

```
setContentDeepLinkId(String deepLinkId, String title, String description, Uri thumbnailUri)
```

EDIT con código aportado por OP:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(getApplication())
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setText("este es el titulo de la publicacion en G+")
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/")
    .setContentDeepLinkId("link",
        "titulo", 
        "descripcion", 
        Uri.parse(imagen)))
    .getIntent();
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Ahi añadi mi codigo a la respuesta. Muchas gracias

Comment: Actualizado! a ver si te ayuda.